# How to create a pivot table with multiple level columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Here's my current code:

```
pd.pivot_table(filtered_dfs[key], values=["Entered Debit Amount", "Entered Credit Amount", "Converted Debit Amount", "Converted Credit Amount"],
                    index=["ATTRIBUTE1 Value for Journal Entry Line DFF", "Segment3"], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

which works out fine and give me this output:

[image]

However I want the segment 3 to be a value to be grouped by as well, example:

[image]

Is there a way to do this with pandas pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
pd.pivot_table(filtered_dfs[key], values=["Entered Debit Amount", "Entered Credit Amount", "Converted Debit Amount", "Converted Credit Amount"],
                index=["ATTRIBUTE1 Value for Journal Entry Line DFF", "Segment3"], aggfunc=np.sum).unstack()
```

Or add `columns` parameter:

```
pd.pivot_table(filtered_dfs[key], values=["Entered Debit Amount", "Entered Credit Amount", "Converted Debit Amount", "Converted Credit Amount"],
                index="ATTRIBUTE1 Value for Journal Entry Line DFF", columns="Segment3", aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Comment: The first solution worked. Thanks!